# 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - can't access anything in mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, database-administration

I just downloaded `mySQL` and  want to start making databases. I can start running `mysql` using the `mysql` command in my terminal. However everything after that (creating databases, adding users, changing password or anything), I keep getting locked out because I don't have a password.

I just installed it so I didn't set any password yet. But it either keeps asking for one which I try different variations of blanks and my computer password but it just says access denied.

For example, I just typed

> mysql> create database test;

but it says `ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'test'`

I looked on the online documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html, and it seems like I'm doing the right thing. I also looked through pages of StackOverflow...

Comment: what platform did you install it on?

Comment: I'm using a mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type `mysql -u root -p` , enter the password which you gave while installing  **MySQL** and then try the command `CREATE DATABASE TEST;` You will see the output as `QUERY OK, 1 ROW AFFECTED`, Then type `USE TEST;` and then create the tables in the `DATABASE`, or use `flush privileges;` and then type `quit`, then start a new session, it should work.

Comment: when I typed mysql -u root -p it prompted me for my password. When installing I used my computer password but it did not work in this case. What password is it referring to?

It says 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: Use the Password which you used while installing MySQL.

Comment: I used my computer password... which is what I typed in here as well.

Comment: It didn't work. I am uninstalling it again and trying again. Thanks for trying to help though.